# How to Transact data from my API to Dynamic 365 API using c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming

My requirement is to Sync my database record to Dynamic 365 and also to authenticate the user.

I am trying with this code but it is not helping me out, Please help me to connect and resolve it

```
string api = "https://ujwl.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0";

AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(api)).Result;

var creds = new ClientCredential("xxx", "xxx");


AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ap.Authority);

var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, creds).Result.AccessToken;

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://ujwl.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$top=2");
}
```

I am not able to authenticate user nor getting the data from the server.
Is this approach correct or I need to go with the different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the solution of above question which I got it by digging into Microsoft Docs

```
string resource = "https://ujwl.crm8.dynamics.com/";
string clientId = "aaaa1111-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-2222bbbbc692";
string redirectUrl = "https://localhost:44345/";

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ujwl.crm8.dynamics.com/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

    response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://ujwl.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only done it on-premise, so I could be wrong... But looks to me that you could/should use the MS c# API. The namespaces are `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` and can be downloaded at he MS page.

Please note that this following code is partial, for on-premise, probably online would have a different connectionstring/parameters.

```
        private IOrganizationService _orgService = null;

        public CrmHelper(string serverHost, int port, string orgName, bool usarSSL, string dominio, string usuario, string password, bool claims)
        {
            /* Nomenclatura usando CLAIMS
 * ServiceUri=https://[server:puerto]/[NombreOrganizacion];
 * AuthType=IFD;
 * Domain=[Dominio];
 * UserName=[Dominio]\[usuario];
 * Password=[Password];
 * LoginPrompt=Never;
 * Organization=[NombreOrganizacion] */

            /* Nomenclatura sin usar CLAIMS: 
 * Url=http://[direccionIP]/[NombreOrganizacion]; 
 * Domain=[Dominio]; 
 * Username=[usuario]; 
 * Password=[Password]; 
 * authtype=AD 
             */
            string formato = claims ? @"ServiceUri={0}://{1}{2}/{3};AuthType=IFD;Domain={4};UserName={4}\{5};Password={6};LoginPrompt=Never;Organization={3}" : @"Url={0}://{1}{2}/{3}; Domain={4}; Username={5}; Password={6}; authtype=AD";
            string connectionString = string.Format(formato, (usarSSL) ? "https" : "http", serverHost, (port == 80) ? "" : ":" + port.ToString(), orgName, dominio, usuario, password);
            CrmServiceClient conn = new Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

            // Cast the proxy client to the IOrganizationService interface.
            _orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

            if (_orgService == null || !conn.IsReady)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No se ha podido conectar al CRM con los parametros facilitados");
            }
        }
```